# WINAPI redrawing bitmaps in client area

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to make image viewer in winapi, 
so basically it loads and draws my first image, but then i click button to navigate through .bmp images in given directory and they are not being drawn.

I would appreciate if you could help me and tell me where I am making mistake.

Here are my WndProc variables:

```
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
HBITMAP img;
std::vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA> vFiles;
std::vector<WIN32_FIND_DATA>::iterator it;
HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFile(L"C:\\Users\\eclip7e\\Pictures\\*.bmp", &file);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
it = vFiles.begin();
it = vFiles.insert(it, file);

while (FindNextFile(hFile, &file))
{
    it = vFiles.insert(it, file);
}
it = vFiles.begin();
    }
```

Here is my button click:

```
    case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {

    case IDC_RIGHT_BUTTON:
    {
        if (it<vFiles.end())
        {
            it++;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        }
        else if (it == vFiles.end())
        {
            it = vFiles.begin();
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        }
    }

    break;
    }

}
break;
```

Here is my WM_PAINT:

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HDC hdcMem;
        LPCWSTR d = L"C:\\Users\\eclip7e\\Pictures\\";
        WIN32_FIND_DATA filex;
        filex = *(it);
        std::wstring df = std::wstring(d) + filex.cFileName;
        LPCWSTR dfc = df.c_str();
        img = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, dfc, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        // Get the bitmap's parameters and verify the get
        BITMAP qBitmap;
        int iReturn = GetObject(reinterpret_cast<HGDIOBJ>(img), sizeof(BITMAP),
            reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(&qBitmap));

        SelectObject(hdcMem, img);
        BOOL bb =BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, qBitmap.bmWidth, qBitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        DeleteDC(hdcMem);
        DeleteObject(img);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: If you have all that code inside your `WndProc` then it gets run EVERY time your window processes a message. Meaning you start with an iterator pointing at the beginning of the vector every time.

Comment: In addition to Jonathan's comment, `if (it<vFiles.end())` is a bug waiting to happen. **Always** compare iterators for equality with `end()`/`rend()`. Valid iterators are not required to compare less than `end()`. You seem to be getting ahead of yourself, though. You first need to understand the basic anatomy of a Windows application. See [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx) for a short introduction.

Comment: thank you, that solves my problem.